# Jagged array of 2d arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio, multidimensional-array

```
private Magazine[,] [] myMags;
```

I'm trying to have a 1d array (length 5) that contains 2d arrays of Magazine[14,14].
So that I could go (ie. each element in the 1d array references a 2d array with 14x14 (=196 Magazines)):

```
myMags[0] = new Magazine[14,14];
myMags[1] = new Magazine[14,14];
myMags[2] = new Magazine[14,14];
myMags[3] = new Magazine[14,14];
myMags[4] = new Magazine[14,14];
```

What is the correct syntax to initialise and assign an element in this manner?

Comment: Why do you need, or want, a 1D array of 2D arrays, vs a real 3D array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Magazine[][,] myMags = new Magazine[5][,];
    myMags[0] = new Magazine[14, 14];
    myMags[1] = new Magazine[14, 14];
    myMags[2] = new Magazine[14, 14];
    myMags[3] = new Magazine[14, 14];
    myMags[4] = new Magazine[14, 14];
```

Comment: This is correct. The order of brackets is somewhat confusing in C#. Note that in the CLR the order is different, and more logical. For example with `myMag` as above, `myMags.GetType().Name` will return `"Magazine[,][]"`, not `"Magazine[][,]"`. And so `typeof(Magazine[,][]).Name == "Magazine[][,]"`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work

```
   private Magazine[,,] myVarName = new Magazine[4,14,14];
```

Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: this doesn't compile, but `Magazine[][,] myVarName = new[] {new Magazine[14,14], ... };` does

Comment: Right, you have an array of 2d arrays I gave an example of a 3d array.

Comment: Hogan, the problem with that is if you want to pass a single 2d array to a function, you can't quickly extract it.  I'm assuming @toop wants to call, for example. `SomeFunction(Magazine[,] array)` passing `array = myVarName[0]`.

Comment: Typically that is called a Jagged array. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca(v=VS.100).aspx.  You should be able to pass a 14 by 14 array as a parameter just fine as long as the size remains constant.  (You might have to do a copy and not an assign.  Jagged arrays allow each element to be a different size -- standard arrays map to a single area of memory.